# how do i get a simple IF function to work in Excel only when another cell has a value in it?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I get a simple IF function to work in Excel only when another cell has a value in it?

I've tried `=IF(ISBLANK(G4)="Sold","Closed","Open")` but that didn't work so I was wondering if anyone could help me.

example-

in cell M4 I want it to read "open" or "closed" but only when cell G4 has a value from a drop down menu selected.

this formula is in M4 - `=IF(G4="Sold","Closed","Open")`

In Other words I would like M4 to remain blank until G4 has a value.

Comment: If you are using data validation for the drop down, you can assign a private function to react based on the drop down selection. Is a macro acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

`=IF(ISBLANK(G4),"",IF(G4="sold","closed","open"))`

this will return blank if blank, "closed" for "sold" and "open" for any other value; Is that what you're looking for?